# Android "Screen Overlay Detected" message if user is trying to grant a permission when a notification is showing

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have Android Marshmallow on a Nexus 6. I am trying to fix the following problem:

If a user is trying to grant permission while a notification is showing, a "Screen overlay detected" message gets displayed and the Request Permission dialog disappears - of course the app does not get the requested permission. (Check screenshot)

I tried to fix the problem by adding "DRAW OVER OTHER APPS" permission - android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW to the manifest but with no luck.

PS: I am sure the problem is caused by the notification. I do not have any app installed that overlays over other apps, I even turned off all apps with "Draw over other apps" permission in the settings. Did not help..

Anyone knows a solution to that problem?

[image]

Comment: see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126798/screen-overlay-detected-dialog

Comment: @gsgsgs I do not have any app that overlays over other apps. Anyway I turned off all apps with "Draw over other apps" permission in the settings. Did not help. As I mentioned in the question, the problem is caused by the notification, not by an app.

Comment: This isn't really something for you to 'fix' in the code. It's a bug in Android (or at best, a poorly thought-out error message) and Google should hopefully fix it in a future release.

Comment: @LearnOpenGLES I think you're right.

Comment: Happens to me when facebook messenger is open(in background)

Comment: This warning is coming because some app is running as screen overlay and might be not visible to you just like apps which shows drawers in arc styles on swipe on screen corners on bottom left or bottom right. Just click on open settings and choose enabled, it will shows all apps having overlay permission, but you just need to find which one is currently running. select that app and disable overlay permission and allow permission in your original app. if you really need to run the app which has overlay then you can enable overlay for it. The problem is only when you install the apps.

Comment: This will also happen if a toast is showing.

Comment: I was searching for a solution while the app was working fine on all other devices except Nexus, sort of thought like a dumb person and restarted the device and that fixed the issue for me :)

Comment: This is an issue in Android M. There might be an application service trying to draw over app for which it always show this dialog prompt. In that case, find out the application and force close or uninstall (in case force close doesn't works). This cannot he handled in code.

Answer (score 74):

In the circumstance that I ran across, I was causing the problem myself.  It was the result of using a `Toast` to display information to the user at the same time that I was asking for permission.  Both of these actions together cause this type of error.

The other answers might resolve someone else's issue. But I wanted to note that you should be cautious of causing your own overlays errors.  Be careful of overlaying something in the view while simultaneously asking for permission.

Comment: I faced the same issue, I removed the toast and it stops appearing.

Comment: Faced the same. Removed Toast and worked like a charm

Comment: The exact same problem solved with this solution. I was showing a toast message just before asking for a permission.

Comment: This solved for me. Was using `Toast` for debugging. This may also be the major reason people are having this.

Comment: `Toast to display information to the user at the same time that I was asking for permission` Helped me..

Answer (score 8):

Uninstall Clean Master app. I uninstalled it and problem solved

Comment: I tried this but did not help . On the contrary , it caused unnecessary un installation.

Comment: I tried this, it **did** help. It caused a necessary un installation. Thanks! (Sony Xperia Z3)

Comment: Uninstalling should not be a solution. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/39826828/2724626 for correct answer.

Comment: In my case, it was `Facebook Messenger`, no need to uninstall, just force stop.

Answer (score 5):

This problem appear because of some culprit application like Twilight, cleaner-master, drupe etc..

To solve this problem you have to disable screen overlay for those culprit apps.

i have moto g4 plus, and this is how i solve this problem

Go to Setting -->  Select Apps ---> again select setting icon in Apps ---> select draw over other apps ---> and disable culprit apps who trouble for other apps.

what i done is checking each apps by disabling this permission and try to run my app, and i found one app this troubling overlay for other apps, so at the end i disabled only this app.

ScreenShots:

[image: Select Apps] [image: select configure setting]

[image: select draw over other apps][image: disable culprit apps]

Comment: MobileGoConnector and Mobile Go Not Show in My Mobile

Comment: What Should i Do now

Comment: @KeshavGera  it will never..  bcz its not internal application, i installed it externally. for you it will be different app that causing overlay issue.. in my case this two application causing overlay problem.

Comment: @KeshavGera you should check each app by disabling overlay permission..

Answer (score 3):

**Got insights from multiple answers here and other forums .**

**Consolidating how I got rid of the issue :**

1. Go to Settings > Apps > (your app which is getting issue)
2. Press on Power button till window for Power off , reboot , airplane mode comes up
3. Hold on Power off option
4. Select reboot in Safe mode
5. Go to settings > apps > (your app which is getting issue)
6. Select whichever permissions you want
7. After Android M update , issues can come up in apps like Messenger , Whatsapp , Prisma etc.

Let me know if any issues .

Note : I am having One plus One mobile.

Comment: But we as developers want the solution to be solved by coding, not through your this (Reboot in Safe Mode) approach.

Comment: You are correct Rakesh , this is not the ideal solution . But till date I haven't any other solution which works for my mobile.

Comment: Worked for me as of now!! Lets hope google fixes it in Nougat+ releases.

Answer (score 2):

This popup is caused by the [manifest.PERMISSION.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission declared by the manifest.

The are 3 categories of permissions, that developer must be aware of :

Normal permission - do nothing with them, just declare in the Manifest

[Vulnerable permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous) - declare in Manifest and ask for permission at first time. They can be changed through system settings.

Above dangerous permissions: **SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW** and **WRITE_SETTINGS** belong to this category. They must be granted, but are not visible in system settings. To request for it you don't use a standard way (int checkSelfPermission (String permission)) but you have to check **Settings.canDrawOverlays()** or **Settings.System.canWrite()** appropriately and if you not do that you will get exception like

> Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1de28ad -- permission denied for this window type

1-Request this permission by yourself in your code just like given below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static int REQUEST_CODE = 10000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (checkDrawOverlayPermission()) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public boolean checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
            Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted my app and turned off my Nexus 6P.  After turning it back on, I reinstalled the app and no longer got the "screen overlay" dialogs when giving the app permissions.

Comment: This is closer to a comment than an answer. You could expand a bit why this works. [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @AgataB  I'm new to StackOverflow.  I didn't have the rights to comment at the time and I didn't know why turning off the phone and uninstalling the app worked, I just thought it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You must disable the overlay for all the apps you see in the list. Only this way can you modify authorizations in the app you need.
I've done that in safe mode, and it worked.
At the end I rebooted the phone and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my Sony Xperia Z3 (Dual Sim) to Android 6.0.1 (Marsmallow). I have been having screen overlay issues. For me i do not have Clean Master, Du Speed, or Du Booster(as the solutions i have read).

So i solved mine looking for any screen overlay apps.

A screen overlap app, is an app that you can use to access other apps on your main home screen without leaving your home screen. So for me the Screen Overlay App here in my situation was the **OMNI SWIPE**. So if you are facing this problem you need to calm down and check which of your app fits the definition of a screen overlay app.

locate the app and uninstall then restart your phone ..

i just finished doing this and am having a good time with the phone

Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

As long as Android 6.x is buggy on some devices where this "overlay alert" is displayed without any reason (on 2 to 5% of the devices according to my analytics data), the best solution is to avoid the whole permission process by defining the targetSdk to 22.

Take care that you can't downgrade the target sdk for a new version or this will induce a INSTALL_FAILED_PERMISSION_DOWNGRADE error when the user updates requiring an unisntall/install of the app.

Answer (score 0):

solution is

remove **Toast** messages from **onRequestPermissionsResult** method

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have granted overlay permission to malicious apps. Go to overlay settings and disable the overlay feature on all apps that don't belong to google and you will be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

I got this problem when installing a new app.
The way I got around this problem is to manually enable the permissions for the newly installed app (before running the app).
I’m pretty sure this is a problem with Android and Samsung devices in particular.
Hope this helps

Answer (score -4):

1. Delete the apps which have screen overlay like CM security, Clean Master, etc.
2. Even delete and try with Messenger (FB app) if needed.

Comment: I tried this but did not help . On the contrary , it caused unnecessary un installation.

Comment: Sometimes there is a reason an app was installed in the first place.

Comment: no. Just reinstall the Clean Master app and/or Facebook messenger app. This solved the problem for  me.