# How Do I determine which app is causing the “Screen Overlay Detected” error?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-overlay

Let me preface this with I have already read through [Android "Screen Overlay Detected" message if user is trying to grant a permission when a notification is showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453759/android-screen-overlay-detected-message-if-user-is-trying-to-grant-a-permissio) and I understand exactly what the overlay problem is.

I also understand how to request it as well as how to check if my current running app has permission to draw on overlays (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)).

I was getting scolded for my app because every time a permission request would popup, the overlays popup would be shown and **even though users gave permission for my application to draw overlays, they could never get past the permissions screen.**

After some digging, the problem was that some users were running a recording app on their screen:

[image]

The problem is, this is not my app! This is AZ Screen Recorder ([link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hecorat.screenrecorder.free&hl=en)) which runs as an overlay, but due to the fact that they are in my app at the time this popup appears, I am blamed for the issue.

I would like to display something to the user that they need to check for any other apps that are running something as an overlay, but I do not know how to check for this.

I can check if they are able to draw overlays in my application, but I do not know how to check for others.

My question therefore is, **is there a way to programmatically check if there are *currently* any apps that are running an overlay at runtime and if so, can I find out the package name of said apps?**

(PS, I have no qualms with the screen recorder app in question, I just wanted to link to it so that anyone can download and test if they choose)

Comment: Hi, Please let me know, if you found any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a test view and generate a tap event on that, then for nougat and oreo versions you can use:

```
view.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if ((event.getFlags() & 0x2) != 0) {
            mPresenter.onVideoViewTapped();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Here 0x2 is the value for FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED, which is hidden as per documentation.

Comment: Interesting idea, ty. I will test this when next I get a chance

Comment: And please share the result too