# Screen Overlay Detected but no solution in StackOverFlow worked for me

Tags: android

My problem is similar to [Android "Screen Overlay Detected" message if user is trying to grant a permission when a notification is showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453759/android-screen-overlay-detected-message-if-user-is-trying-to-grant-a-permissio)

But non of the solutions listed below work for me, I disabled all other apps that access overlay, but still no positive response same error.

What should I do to solve this.

Is this my development app error OR android system error? OR any other?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution ,

Just install **Install Button Unlocker** from [HERE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sfapps.installbuttonunlocker&hl=en)

and follow the instructions mentioned in that application description.