# Android app Screen Overlay Detected

Tags: android, android-permissions

The following error occurs while running my android app:

> Screen Overlay Detected:
>
> To change this permission setting, you first have to turn off screen overlay from Settings > Apps

and my app is not listed in the list shown.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Have a look into [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453759/android-screen-overlay-detected-message-if-user-is-trying-to-grant-a-permissio). maybe help. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when you are trying to show a Toast when an alert dialog is already been displayed or vice versa(well there are other reason as well but newbies mostly face this problem). Structure your UX flow so that you don't show both of them at the same time.